# How to install and configure mysql with saltstack

Tags: python, mysql, salt-stack

As I know to execute any mysql functions from salt master, we need to install mysql python package on mysql minion. So I installed it on minion as follows.
sudo apt-get install phython-mysqldb

After that I edited /etc/salt/minion file to add the following at the end of the file

```
mysql.host: ‘localhost’ mysql.port: 3306 mysql.user: ‘root’ mysql.pass: ‘’ mysql.db: ‘mysql’ mysql.charset: ‘utf8′
```

Then I restarted the minion,

```
sudo service salt-minion restart
```

Now, from salt master if I run any command, it's not receiving the response from the minion. When I remove that added line from /etc/salt/minion file, it receives response output from the minion. What's wrong am I doing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your settings are slightly mis-formatted. There might be an issue with the quotes.

I tried these and it works for me.

```
mysql.host: 'localhost'
mysql.port: 3306
mysql.user: 'root'
mysql.pass: ''
mysql.db: 'mysql'
mysql.charset: 'utf8'
```

Please note that these are the default settings anyway, no need to add them as long as you don't change i.e. the password.

Answer (score 0):

Salt uses it's own version of python so if you try to install package using pip install it wont find the package.

Here is what worked for me

`salt pip install pymysql`